# Where can I find candy-machine version 1?

Tags: metaplex

I'm looking for `candy-machine` version 1 codebase for to easy examples for token-metadata implementation. I wasn't able to find it anywhere on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CMv1 program is located at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/florida/tree/main/nft-candy-machine